# Adwords API: Select Ads with empty impression

Tags: java, scala, google-ads-api

After days of pain and suffering I managed to understand what the the documentation was trying to say and got a connection to the Adwords API, then on a frenzy rush I even managed to get some data out of it. Fooling myself I thought I had it untill I had to get some ads with a where clause.

My end goal for now would be simply to get all the Ads that have 0 impressions.

I have checked the [java code examples](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-java-lib/tree/master/examples/adwords_axis/src/main/java/adwords/axis/v201402) and many SO posts, of course I also checked the [Adwords documentation](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/overview) and I couldn't find what I was looking for. On the last one there's "[AdGroupAdService: Create, update, and delete ads](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/reference/v201402/AdGroupAdService)", so as far as I understand this is the service I should use, my (Scala) code looks like this:

```
val adwordsCredentials = new OfflineCredentials.Builder().forApi(Api.ADWORDS).fromFile().build().generateCredential()
val adwordsSession = new AdWordsSession.Builder().fromFile().withOAuth2Credential(adwordsCredentials).build()
val adgroupService = new AdWordsServices().get(adwordsSession, classOf[AdGroupAdServiceInterface])

def getAds() = {
  val builder = new SelectorBuilder()
  val selector = builder
    .fields("Id", "Name", "Status", "AdGroupId")
    .offset(0)
    .limit(100)
    .build()

  val results = adgroupService.get(selector)

  if (results.getEntries() != null) {
    results.getEntries().foreach( row => {
      println(row.getAd.getId)
    })
  }
}
```

1) There's no `getAd.getClicks` or `getAd.getImpressions`, I digged the `Ad.java` class and the only fields available are this:

```
id;
url;
displayUrl;
devicePreference;
adType;
```

2) If I add `Clicks` to the query I get `faultString: [SelectorError.INVALID_FIELD_NAME @ serviceSelector; trigger:'Clicks']`, supposedly because the campaign doesn't have a field `Clicks`;

3) Are reports the only way of doing this?

Looks like something fairly easy to do, yet I couldn't find a way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google removed all stats fields from several of its Adwords API services, including AdGroupAdService, with [the release of v201309](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/guides/migration/v201309).

You will need to use [AD_PERFORMANCE_REPORT](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/appendix/reports#ad).  Within the selector of your report definition, set a [predicate](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/reference/v201402/CampaignService.Predicate) to include only rows where the Impressions field has a value of 0.